# Zookeeper randomly loses node

Tags: apache-zookeeper

Environment: zookeeper v3.4.8, jre 1.8.0_73, Windows 7

Setup three nodes. Everything comes up Ok but after a random amount of time ( >5 minutes) the quorum fails. I've tried adjusting the ticktime from the default of 2000 to 10000 which is the amount of milliseconds in a Windows tick. Any ideas why it I'm loosing a node?

The actual IP has been replaced with xx.x.xx
Node 1 error:

```
2016-03-01 14:26:44,836 [myid:1] - WARN  [WorkerSender[myid=1]:QuorumCnxManager@400] - Cannot open channel to 2 at election address /xx.x.xx.52:3889
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectOne(QuorumCnxManager.java:381)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.toSend(QuorumCnxManager.java:354)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection$Messenger$WorkerSender.process(FastLeaderElection.java:452)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection$Messenger$WorkerSender.run(FastLeaderElection.java:433)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-03-01 14:26:44,836 [myid:1] - INFO  [WorkerSender[myid=1]:QuorumPeer$QuorumServer@149] - Resolved hostname: xx.x.xx.52 to address: /xx.x.xx.52
2016-03-01 14:26:45,103 [myid:1] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=1]/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:2181:Learner@326] - Getting a diff from the leader 0x0
2016-03-01 14:26:45,118 [myid:1] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=1]/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:2181:FileTxnSnapLog@240] - Snapshotting: 0x0 to C:\zookeeper-3.4.8\data\version-2\snapshot.0
2016-03-01 14:26:45,822 [myid:1] - INFO  [WorkerReceiver[myid=1]:FastLeaderElection@600] - Notification: 1 (message format version), 3 (n.leader), 0x0 (n.zxid), 0x1 (n.round), LOOKING (n.state), 3 (n.sid), 0x1 (n.peerEpoch) FOLLOWING (my state)
2016-03-01 14:26:48,693 [myid:1] - INFO  [/xx.x.xx.82:3888:QuorumCnxManager$Listener@541] - Received connection request /xx.x.xx.52:60858
2016-03-01 14:26:48,693 [myid:1] - INFO  [WorkerReceiver[myid=1]:FastLeaderElection@600] - Notification: 1 (message format version), 2 (n.leader), 0x100000000 (n.zxid), 0x1 (n.round), LOOKING (n.state), 2 (n.sid), 0x1 (n.peerEpoch) FOLLOWING (my state)
2016-03-01 14:41:46,010 [myid:1] - WARN  [RecvWorker:3:QuorumCnxManager$RecvWorker@810] - Connection broken for id 3, my id = 1, error =
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:203)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager$RecvWorker.run(QuorumCnxManager.java:795)
2016-03-01 14:41:46,011 [myid:1] - WARN  [RecvWorker:3:QuorumCnxManager$RecvWorker@813] - Interrupting SendWorker
2016-03-01 14:41:46,011 [myid:1] - WARN  [SendWorker:3:QuorumCnxManager$SendWorker@727] - Interrupted while waiting for message on queue
java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2014)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2088)
    at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.poll(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:418)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.pollSendQueue(QuorumCnxManager.java:879)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.access$500(QuorumCnxManager.java:65)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager$SendWorker.run(QuorumCnxManager.java:715)
2016-03-01 14:41:46,013 [myid:1] - WARN  [SendWorker:3:QuorumCnxManager$SendWorker@736] - Send worker leaving thread
```

Node 2 error:

```
2016-03-01 14:41:48,977 [myid:2] - WARN  [RecvWorker:3:QuorumCnxManager$RecvWorker@810] - Connection broken for id 3, my id = 2, error =
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager$RecvWorker.run(QuorumCnxManager.java:795)
2016-03-01 14:41:48,977 [myid:2] - WARN  [RecvWorker:3:QuorumCnxManager$RecvWorker@813] - Interrupting SendWorker
2016-03-01 14:41:48,977 [myid:2] - WARN  [SendWorker:3:QuorumCnxManager$SendWorker@727] - Interrupted while waiting for message on queue
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.poll(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.pollSendQueue(QuorumCnxManager.java:879)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.access$500(QuorumCnxManager.java:65)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager$SendWorker.run(QuorumCnxManager.java:715)
2016-03-01 14:41:48,977 [myid:2] - WARN  [SendWorker:3:QuorumCnxManager$SendWorker@736] - Send worker leaving thread
```

Node 3 error:

```
2016-03-01 14:41:45,460 [myid:3] - WARN  [RecvWorker:1:QuorumCnxManager$RecvWorker@810] - Connection broken for id 1, my id = 3, error =
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager$RecvWorker.run(QuorumCnxManager.java:795)
2016-03-01 14:41:45,460 [myid:3] - WARN  [RecvWorker:1:QuorumCnxManager$RecvWorker@813] - Interrupting SendWorker
2016-03-01 14:41:45,460 [myid:3] - WARN  [SendWorker:1:QuorumCnxManager$SendWorker@727] - Interrupted while waiting for message on queue
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.poll(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.pollSendQueue(QuorumCnxManager.java:879)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.access$500(QuorumCnxManager.java:65)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager$SendWorker.run(QuorumCnxManager.java:715)
2016-03-01 14:41:45,460 [myid:3] - WARN  [SendWorker:1:QuorumCnxManager$SendWorker@736] - Send worker leaving thread
2016-03-01 14:41:48,393 [myid:3] - WARN  [RecvWorker:2:QuorumCnxManager$RecvWorker@810] - Connection broken for id 2, my id = 3, error =
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager$RecvWorker.run(QuorumCnxManager.java:795)
2016-03-01 14:41:48,393 [myid:3] - WARN  [RecvWorker:2:QuorumCnxManager$RecvWorker@813] - Interrupting SendWorker
2016-03-01 14:41:48,393 [myid:3] - WARN  [SendWorker:2:QuorumCnxManager$SendWorker@727] - Interrupted while waiting for message on queue
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.poll(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.pollSendQueue(QuorumCnxManager.java:879)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.access$500(QuorumCnxManager.java:65)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager$SendWorker.run(QuorumCnxManager.java:715)
2016-03-01 14:41:48,393 [myid:3] - WARN  [SendWorker:2:QuorumCnxManager$SendWorker@736] - Send worker leaving thread
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have Vmware installed on one of the machines. We discovered (netstat -an) that even though we specified the IP of the Windows ethernet adapter in zoo.cfg that zookeeper had in fact bound to the IP of the virtual ethernet adapter created by VmWare. Everything worked fine once we disabled the virtual ethernet adapters.